# My android application is not working with respect to activity life cycle

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle, android-studio-3.0, flashlight

I'm making flashlight application with handling Activity Life Cycle. The application is running fine but the problem occurs when i call onStop(); while flashlight is on ,when I return from the onStop();, the application should turn on flash light but it doesn't. 
I have tried all the methods but the flashOn(); is not enabling the flashlight. I had checked from debugging that the application do nothing if the flashlight was on after returning from onStop();

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton imagebtn;
ImageView img;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash = false;
private Camera.Parameters params;

private boolean flag= false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imagebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    img = findViewById(R.id.torchimage);

    isFlashOn = false;
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        // If device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                finish();//Close application
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }


    imagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {

                flashOff();
            } else {

                flashOn();
            }
        }
    });
}


protected void checkCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


**protected void flashOn() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {


       {
                if (camera == null || params == null) {
                    return;
                }

            /*if (flag==true) {
flag=false;
                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
            */}

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
        toggleImages();
        btnSound();
    }
}**

protected void flashOff() {
    if (isFlashOn)
        {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();

        isFlashOn = false;
            toggleImages();
        btnSound();

    }
}

protected void btnSound() {
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_sound);
    mp.start();
}

public void toggleImages() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        imagebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_on);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.torch_on);
    } else {
        imagebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_off);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.torch_off);
    }
}

@Override


 protected void onDestroy() {
      //  Toast.makeText(this,"OnDestroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (isFlashOn)
            flashOn();
        else
            flashOff();

    }

    @Override
   protected void onRestart(){    super.onRestart();

            if (isFlashOn==true)
                flashOn();
            else
                flashOff();

    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (isFlashOn == true)
            flashOn();
        else
            flashOff();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
  // Toast.makeText(this,"OnStart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//  if (hasFlash)
      checkCamera();


}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
//    Toast.makeText(this, "OnStop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onStop();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
       camera = null;
       flag= true;

    }

}
```

Comment: this case its reached onstop but its not on flash ?

Comment: @sasikumar when onStop is called while Flashlight is on. But on Restarting app the flash doesn't on camera

Answer (score 1):

Please look again at the Android lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

It goes onStop -> onRestart -> onStart -> onResume

You have an awful lot of crap spread all over the place making what should be easy to see, rather difficult.

So... the flash is on ie isFlashOn = true;

Remove the boolean == true from the if while you're at it. Just if (boolean) works and is much better.

onStop... camera = null; flag= true;

But isFlashOn is still true

Returned to Activity...

onRestart... if (isFlashOn==true) flashOn(); <--- It is, so going to flashOn()

flashOn() {
    if (!isFlashOn) { <------------- No the boolean is still true so this isn't run... camera is null anyway.

onStart... checkCamera() {
    if (camera == null) { <------ Yes, OK

onResume... if (isFlashOn == true) <----- Again same problem, so camera never starts.

Set isFlashOn = false in onStop

Also remove code from resume or restart... its just duplicated and going through the same thing twice.

Hopefully this teaches you how to debug better. Learn from it.

Comment: I had made changes what you have recommended. But the problem is same @cmosBattery
now on Start it doesn't gets the camera.